# Matlab cellfun on function strfind

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell

I want to use `cellfun` function on `strfind` function to find the index of each string in a cell array of string in another cell array of strings to exclude them from it.

```
strings = {'aaa','bbb','ccc','ddd','eee','fff','ggg','hhh','iii','jjj'};
excludedStrings = {'b','g','h'};
idx = cellfun('strfind',strings,excludedStrings);
idx = cell2mat = idx;
idx = reshap(idx,numel(idx),1);
idx = unique(idx);
strings(cell2mat(idx)) = [];
```

There's error in the `cellfun` call line, how can I fix this?

Comment: Does `cellfun( @(x) strfind(strings,x), excludedStrings, 'UniformOutput', 0 )` come close to what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a lovely one-liner:

```
strings = regexprep(strings, excludedStrings, '');
```

Breakdown:

- All the words/characters to search for are passed on to `regexprep`
- This function replaces every occurrence of *any* word/character in the set given above, with the empty string (`''`).

It will automatically repeat this action on all elements in the cell-array `string`.

If you also wish to remove any empty strings from the cell `string`, do this after the command above:

```
strings = strings(~cellfun('isempty', strings));
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this wouldn't work properly if `excludedStrings` contains strings with more than one character...
I believe this works better: `strings = regexprep(strings, excludedStrings, '')`. I also suggest `strings = strings(~cellfun(@isempty, strings))` to remove the "empty" strings.

Comment: @EitanT: now it works. Regarding your last statement: I'm not sure if the OP indeed wants that...

Comment: @EitanT: Anyway, always use `cellfun('isempty', strings)`; it's over 10 times faster than `cellfun(@isempty, strings)`.

Comment: Oh, my last statement was based on the following OP's attempt: `strings(cell2mat(idx)) = [];` Regarding the `isempty`, I just timed those two puppies and it seems that `@isempty` is rougly x2 faster. Are you sure about this? (P.S I'm running it on R2009a)... +1 anyway.

Comment: @EitanT: `tic, for ii = 1:1e4, cellfun('isempty', strings); end; toc`: Elapsed time is 0.056434 seconds. `tic, for ii = 1:1e4, cellfun(@isempty, strings); end; toc`: Elapsed time is 0.288836 seconds. OK, maybe not 10 times, but certainly much faster. Even worse: `tic, for ii = 1:1e4, cellfun(@(x)isempty(x), strings); end; toc`: Elapsed time is 4.333200 seconds.

Comment: You're right. For the first iteration `@isempty` runs x2 faster. For the rest it runs x2 slower... I've run into these issues before, but I never figured why it is so.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're after this:

```
idx = cellfun(@(str) any(cellfun(@(pat) any(strfind(str,pat)),excludedStrings)),strings)

idx =
    0     1     0     0     0     0     1     1     0     0
```

after which you can of course apply:

```
strings(idx) = [];
```

Because you have two cell arrays which you want to cross-check (of which one is an array), you need to nest two `cellfun`s.