# Batch strfind: finding lots of strings within lots of other strings

Tags: string, matlab, vectorization, cell-array

**Question:** I have a two large cell arrays of strings `A` and `B`. I want to know the fastest way to identify which elements in `A` contain which in `B`. In particular, can it be done without looping?

**Minimal Example:** (my actual `A` and `B` contain 7,000,000 and 22,000 strings, respectively)

```
A = {'one';
     'two';
     'three';
     'four'};
B = {'ee';
     'xx';
     'r'};
```

The desired output for the example would be

```
C = [ 0 0 0 ;
      0 0 0 ;
      1 0 1 ;
      0 0 1 ];
```

where rows and columns of `C` correspond to the elements of `A` and `B` respectively. For my purpose, I only need a true/false answer but bonus points if `C` returns the first index of *where* the string in `B` is in `A`, e.g.:

```
C = [ 0 0 0 ;
      0 0 0 ;
      4 0 3 ;
      0 0 4 ];
```

**What I've tried:** [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13289258/matlab-cellfun-on-function-strfind) post is similar, except they're looking for strings *excluding* other strings, so that `regexp` provides a nice solution -- I don't think this applies here. For us, looping does the job, but too slowly:

```
for i=1:length(A);
    for j=1:length(B);
        C(i,j) = max([0,strfind(A{i},B{j})]); disp(C(i,j));
    end
end
```

Or, basically the same thing, but with `cellfun`:

```
AA = repmat(A,[1 length(B)]);
BB = repmat(B,[length(A) 1]);
C  = reshape(cellfun(@(a,b) max([0,strfind(a,b)]),AA(:),BB(:)),[length(A),length(B)]);
```

**Bigger Example:** 
I tested the `cellfun` method on some bigger arrays (still smaller than what I need):

```
N=10000; M=200;
A=cellstr(char(randi([97,122],[N,10])));  %// N random length 10 lowercase strings
B=cellstr(char(randi([97,122],[M,4])));   %// M random length 4 lowercase strings

tic;
AA=repmat(A,[1 length(B)]);
BB=repmat(B,[length(A) 1]);
C=reshape(cellfun(@(a,b) max([0,strfind(a,b)]),AA(:),BB(:)),[length(A),length(B)]); 
toc

Elapsed time is 21.91 seconds.
```

Any ideas? Could `regexp` help? Could `ismember` help? Am I stuck looping?

Comment: So your output matrix is supposed to be a 7,000,000 x 22,000 matrix? That doesn't sound like a matrix which can be handled memory-wise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally I'd suggest, that your expected output matrix will be to big memory-wise and you need do rethink your approach anyway.

If you'd have a smaller dataset, you can do it as follows:

```
A = {'one';
     'two';
     'three';
     'four'};
B = {'ee';
     'xx';
     'r'};

%// generate indices
n = numel(A);
m = numel(B);
[xi,yi] = ndgrid(1:n,1:m);

%// matching
Ax = A(xi);
By = B(yi);
temp = regexp(Ax,By,'start');

%// localize empty cell elements
%// cellfun+@isempty is quite fast
emptyElements = cellfun(@isempty, temp);

%// generate output
out = zeros(n,m);
out(~emptyElements) = [temp{:}];
```

---

```
out =

     0     0     0
     0     0     0
     4     0     3
     0     0     4
```

Comment: Nice touch dealing with the empty elements.

Comment: Beautiful, exactly what I was looking for. And you're right about the memory problem as well. FWIW I should have mentioned that in my case I expect `C` to be very sparse, and that I don't necessarily need `C` in that format. Just getting the indices `[Ci,Cj]=find(~cellfun(@isempty,temp))` would be enough... though I'm not sure that problem is any more feasible in terms of memory

Comment: I'm glad that I could help!

Comment: @Geoff Instead of `find(~cellfun(@isempty,temp))` the following should be suffient: `[temp{:}]` find is very slow for big datasets!